# how to convert an image into base64 string

Tags: android, xml, encoding, base64, encode

I want to convert image to base 64 encode to string. from that   to send to server with `oma_status-icon` xml format.

but I am getting unsupported encoding from the server response....

is there any other way to convert image to base64 string??

plz..help...

my code is:

```
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.image);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

         String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

Comment: if this helpful then accept answers so other people may helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please use this code..

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.image);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Please import**

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

Comment: Base64.DEFAULT :- Passing DEFAULT results in output that adheres to RFC 2045.

Comment: String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);  at that i am getting base64.DEFAULT error.....how can follow??

Comment: base64.DEFAULT  not samll base64 used Base64.DEFAULT

Comment: when I am sending with this string in  xml format of oma_status-icon through http  put reqest i am getting unsupported encoding.....

Comment: i think may be check in server side. i have given code is 100% working in my application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16358/discussion-between-nik-and-subbareddy-polamreddy)

Answer (score 3):

```
// convert from bitmap to byte array
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// get the base 64 string
String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(someImg), 
                       Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte b [] = baos.toByteArray();
String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Dont forget to `import android.util.Base64;`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try

`String base64Result = Base64.encodeToString(yourByteArray[], Base64.DEFAULT);`

Answer (score 1):

Method:

```
private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Imports:

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
```