# How to change or transform an ImageView to a object or a string?

Tags: android, object, imageview

How to change or transform an ImageView to a object or a string? So, I can send that imagview as a String to API.

Example, I have 4 id imageview from xml :

```
@+id/q1
@+id/q2
@+id/q3
@+id/q4
```

and i want to change all those imageviews to be a string in Java. So, i can send them to API as a JSON like this :

```
 {
     option_code: 'rp001o001', 
     option_value: 'Likuiditas dan keamanan investasi'
    }
```

`option_code: 'rp001o001'` is the paramater that i get from ImageView. How to make it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to send the `ImageView`, or an image from `ImageView`? There is no sense sending ImageView.

Comment: send image and seperate parameter id of Imageview if required in json

Comment: the logic is I have 1 question with 4 answers, each answer is a ImageView or ImageButton. I want to send each image with different id to API as a value of paramater "option_code" @VladMatvienko

Comment: do you want to send an image, or it's ID?

Comment: i want to send an image as a object, like change a image to be a string or a object. So, the image that i send to API is option_code: 'rp001o001'.

'rp001o001' is the value of the image that i send. is it possible? @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

byte[] is best way to send data from android phone  to server , You need to convert Image into byte[] check below method

// convert from bitmap to byte array

```
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

// get the base 64 string

```
String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(someImg), 
                       Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Thank for this guy -https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333971/4741746

Answer (score 0):

First get the image as an bitmap from the imageview and convert them into base64 string. Here's how you do it:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmapOrg= drawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Here ba1 is your image string.

Answer (score -1):

just convert your image to a base 64 string and store it in your server and do the reverse to show the image in your app later

[how to convert an image into base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297381/how-to-convert-an-image-into-base64-string)